# accessing JSON value in array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following JSON object

```
[
  {
    'parameter-name': 'device',
    enabled: true,
    value: '077743322L102515',
    description: 'device identifier. Should be used only when multiple devices are connected at once'
  },
  {
    'parameter-name': 'app_id',
    enabled: true,
    value: 'com.instagram.andrpbj',
    description: ' when using this parameter, you are able to use Insomniac on a cloned Instagram-application. Just provide the new package name'
  },
  {
    'parameter-name': 'old',
    enabled: false,
    value: 'True',
    description: 'add this flag to use an old version of uiautomator. Use it only if you experience problems with the default version'
  }
]
```

i wanted to access the value of the parameter-name: 'old', by value i mean value
is there a one step solution to do that without iterating through each entry ?

Comment: That's not JSON, it's just an object. It's not quite clear what you're asking. If you're searching for the _value_ `old` you already have the value in a variable as your search criteria, don't you?

Comment: Let us assume you want to change the `value` to `"False"` for `parameter-name` = `"old"`,  and your array of objects is named `data`, please try this: `data.find(ob => ob["parameter-name"] === 'old').value = "False";` and share your feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my point of view, using [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is the cleanest solution to get the value:

```js
const { value } = data.find((obj) => obj['parameter-name'] === 'old');
```

If your goal is to edit the value as you're asking in the comment, you can get the index of the targeted object within the array using [Array.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and then edit the data:

```js
const objIdx = data.findIndex((obj) => obj['parameter-name'] === 'old');
data[objIdx].value = 'newValue'
```

Instead of getting the index, you could even manipulate the value on the object directly:

```js
const obj = data.find((obj) => obj['parameter-name'] === 'old');
obj.value = 'newValue';
```

Code Snippet

```js
const data = [{
    'parameter-name': 'device',
    enabled: true,
    value: '077743322L102515',
    description: 'device identifier. Should be used only when multiple devices are connected at once'
  },
  {
    'parameter-name': 'app_id',
    enabled: true,
    value: 'com.instagram.andrpbj',
    description: ' when using this parameter, you are able to use Insomniac on a cloned Instagram-application. Just provide the new package name'
  },
  {
    'parameter-name': 'old',
    enabled: false,
    value: 'True',
    description: 'add this flag to use an old version of uiautomator. Use it only if you experience problems with the default version'
  }
];

const obj = data.find((obj) => obj['parameter-name'] === 'old');
obj.value = 'newValue';

console.log(data);
```

---

In order to account for a situation where the 'searched-value' is not found, it may be better to split the assignment like this:

```
const foundObj = data?.find((obj) => obj['parameter-name'] === 'old');
if (foundObj) foundObj.value = 'newValue';
```

```js
const data = [{
    'parameter-name': 'device',
    enabled: true,
    value: '077743322L102515',
    description: 'device identifier. Should be used only when multiple devices are connected at once'
  },
  {
    'parameter-name': 'app_id',
    enabled: true,
    value: 'com.instagram.andrpbj',
    description: ' when using this parameter, you are able to use Insomniac on a cloned Instagram-application. Just provide the new package name'
  },
  {
    'parameter-name': 'old',
    enabled: false,
    value: 'True',
    description: 'add this flag to use an old version of uiautomator. Use it only if you experience problems with the default version'
  }
];

const foundObj = data?.find((obj) => obj['parameter-name'] === 'old');
if (foundObj) foundObj.value = 'newValue';

console.log(data);
```

Comment: how do i edit the value in the object?

Comment: @aherlambang I've updated the answer with an explanation how to edit the value.

Comment: If my thinking is correct, `Array.find()` would provide the object (ie, reference). So, instead of destructuring the `value`, if one holds the object itself like: `const foundObj = data.find...` then, `foundObj.value = ....` should suffice. Worth a shot, I think.

Comment: @jsN00b Indeed, haven't thought about that one. Please, feel free to edit the answer adding this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.filter((value) => {
  if(value['parameter-name'] === 'old'){
     console.log(value);
  }
})
```

Comment: You cannot access `parameter-name` via a dot notation in Javascript due to the dash in the name. You can however use the dictionary approach `value['parameter-name']`

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Alexander's answer if you don't want to mutate the array object directly.

It's a very generic function that accepts a query object (key, oldValue, newValue) so it will work on all the property keys, not just `parameter-name`.

It [`finds`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the object that matches the query criteria (if nothing is found the function returns `null`), [`filters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the objects that *don't* match the query criteria, and then returns that filtered array with a new updated object.

```js
const arr=[{"parameter-name":"device",enabled:!0,value:"077743322L102515",description:"device identifier. Should be used only when multiple devices are connected at once"},{"parameter-name":"app_id",enabled:!0,value:"com.instagram.andrpbj",description:" when using this parameter, you are able to use Insomniac on a cloned Instagram-application. Just provide the new package name"},{"parameter-name":"old",enabled:!1,value:"True",description:"add this flag to use an old version of uiautomator. Use it only if you experience problems with the default version"}];

// Accept an array, and a query object
function change(arr, query) {

  // Destructure the query
  const { key, oldValue, newValue } = query;

  // Look for the object where the value
  // of the key specified in the query
  // matches the oldValue
  const found = arr.find(obj => {
    return obj[key] === oldValue;
  });

  // If there isn't a match return null
  if (!found) return null;

  // Otherwise `filter` out the objects that
  // don't match the criteria...
  const filtered = arr.filter(obj => {
    return obj[key] !== oldValue;
  });

  // Destructure all the object properties
  // away from the property we want to update
  const { [key]: temp, ...rest } = found;
  
  // Return a new array with a new updated object
  return [ ...filtered, { [key]: newValue, ...rest } ];

}

const query = {
  key: 'parameter-name',
  oldValue: 'old',
  newValue: 'new'
};

console.log(change(arr, query));

const query2 = {
  key: 'value',
  oldValue: '077743322L102515',
  newValue: '999999999'
};

console.log(change(arr, query2));
```